# Xamarin ios PushViewController not working in tabbed page

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Currently I am calling a forms content page from a native page.
I have 2 tabs-Tab1 ,Tab2

in Tab2 I want to embed a forms content page called ContentPage1,Here are the codes-

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
           UIViewController contentPage1= new ContentPage1().CreateViewController();
        contentPage1.Title = "Test embedding forms";
        contentPage1.NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;

        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(contentPage1 , true);
    }
```

codes in storyboard-

```
<scene sceneID="test">
     <objects>
       <viewController storyboardIdentifier="ContentPage1" modalTransitionStyle="partialCurl" id="test1" customClass="ContentPage1Controller" sceneMemberID="viewController">
         <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="test2">
         <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
       <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
       <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="test4"/></view><extendedEdge key="edgesForExtendedLayout"/>
       <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="test3"/>
       </viewController><placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="test5" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/></objects>

  </scene>
```

And using this codes ,I am able to sucessfully launch the forms page(contentPage1) when I click Tab2.
But for second time when i click it the page just disappears...For example when Click Tab2 for first time it works,but when I click Tab1 and then again click to Tab2,It just disappears,nothing shows up..Need help on this..

Comment: You code seems has no issue. You can provide a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: For security purpose i cannot provide,entire codes...But basically in my controller i have these codes,and i am binding this controller in storyboard like other controllers..I am able to get other controllers data when i click the tabs which are designed natively,facing problem only with controller which has forms embedded.I have added the storyboard codes

Comment: You can create a sample which contains the issue , your code works fine on my side. Maybe I misunderstood what your means .

Comment: I will create a sample..and will post it here...in the mean time..Could you please create tabs and see that its working,atleast i will be confirmed that bug is in my codes...because some where i was seeing that its a bug if we use tabbcontroller and pushviewcontroller(some memory issue)

Comment: If this is a common issue , it would have been found out  some days before .So I think maybe there are some issue in your code .